# Embed youtube videos without uiwebview?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube

I have googled this for a few days and cannot find the answer.

Is it possible to embed youtube videos within xcode without the need for the uiwebview.

This is why.

My app will be using potentially hundreds of youtube clips and I have since discovered that
1. Uiwebview is memory intensive
2. Cannot be reused or recycled as with cache problems.

Thus I looked into the media player framework and found that when the video is clicked, youtube kicks in and takes over the app. Which is not desirable.

Does anybody know if a repo which resolves this or point me in the correct direction.

Sorry for the lack of code but I do not think it will aid in this question.

One last note, I ended up using jquery mobile and phone gap as a quick fix but I'm finding the user experience to be clunky and slow.

Comment: Unrelated to Xcode, retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check ... [HCYoutubeParser for iOS](http://www.readability.com/articles/pyxttmh3) .. and.. [LBYouTubeView for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/lbyoutubeview)

Comment: Thanks, ill check them out and report my findings :)

Comment: LBYouTubeView works better then expected. Thanks so Much Tony :)